# Can rules of inference be used in one side of an implication?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to understand rules of inference and I am not sure if they can be used in this way. For example, let's say we have the premises:

(a) $(p ∧ q) → (r ∨ s)$

(b) $¬s$

Can it be concluded that $p ∧ q → r$ from applying a disjunctive syllogism to the conclusion of (a) along with (b)? Or in a more general way can rules of inference be used in one side of an implication?

Comment: This depends on your rules of inference; you might have to apply several rules. The conclusion is certainly logically valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(p \land q) \Rightarrow r$ is deducible, but it depends on what tools you're allowed to use. For example, you might be able to perform the following:

\begin{align}
((p \land q) \Rightarrow (r \lor s)) &\Leftrightarrow ((\lnot(p \land q)) \lor (r \lor s)) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (((\lnot(p \land q)) \lor r) \lor s)
\end{align}

and now introduce $\lnot s$, perform your disjunctive alternative to conclude $(\lnot(p \land q)) \lor r$, and convert that back to the implication $(p \land q) \Rightarrow r$.

Another way to get to the second side of the implication is the deduction theorem: if you assume a formula $\mathcal{S}$ and wind up establishing a formula $\mathcal{T}$, then you may conclude $\mathcal{S} \Rightarrow \mathcal{T}$.

So, if this is available to you, you can start by assuming $p \land q$. From (a) you get $r \lor s$. Now introduce $\lnot s$, perform your disjunctive alternative to get $r$. Now you can conclude $(p \land q) \Rightarrow r$.